# Error with arrayfun

Tags: matlab

I have the following function:

```
function x = dataParser(y)

    %// Importing list of places
    places = textread('UKPlaceNames.txt' ,'%s');

    %// Picking two places

    place = char(places(y)); %// Converting them to an array of chars
    placeInt = place - 'A' + 1;
    x = placeInt;
end
```

In a separate function, I create:

```
myVector = 1:6
```

and then call

```
myVectorB = arrayfun(dataParser, myVector)
```

However, MATLAB throws an error on:

```
place = char(places(y));
```

stating that there are not enough parameters, where

```
places = textread('test.txt' ,'%s');
```

I am a bit confused as to where the error is, since the function takes one paramater and I am providing it...

Thanks!

Comment: what are the contents of `y`? The `char` function takes 1 input and works even if it is empty

Comment: Can you show example of dataParser function? What does it do?

Comment: function x = dataParser(y)

    % Importing list of places
    places=textread('UKPlaceNames.txt' ,'%s'); 

    % Picking two places
    place = char(places(y));
   

    % Converting them to an array of chars
    placeInt = place - 'A' + 1;
    
    x = placeInt;

end

Comment: Not sure if this is related or not, but shouldn't there be `@` in `arrayfun(@dataParser, myVector)`?

Answer (score 0):

You should do the following in your main script/function:

```
myVectorB = arrayfun(@dataParser, myVector)
```

Note the `@` in front of `dataParser`: this passes a function handle of `dataParser` to `arrayfun`, instead of evaluating the function `dataParser()` and passing the result to `arrayfun`.